# Redirecting thousands pages, httphandler asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

I need to redirect thousands of pages from old urls to news. I solved problem with dynamic routing, but know I need to redirect every old links.
So I try to do some httphandler – my code is here only for firs testing is here:

```
namespace BoardRider
{
    public class RedirectHandler : IHttpHandler
    {

        #region IHttpHandler Members

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            Uri uri = context.Request.Url;

            if (uri.AbsoluteUri.Contains("default2.aspx"))
            {
                string red = uri.AbsoluteUri;

                context.Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

In web.config I have this:

```
<handlers>
  <add  type="BoardRider.RedirectHandler" path="*" name="RedirectHandler" verb="*"  />
</handlers>
```

If I write into my handler some response.write text and in web.config I put into path for example *.exam and I write localhost://webroot/handler.exam – it works. So I think, that my http handler is registered successfully.

But if I change path to “*”, like in example above, there is some strange behavior.

If I write address localhost://webroot/default2.aspx – it redirects to default.aspx. I can see this address in address line. But I can’t see any content of page.

If I write address localhost://webroot/Events?id=2525 – I get error page “The WebResource.axd handler must be registered in the configuration to process this request.”

Please, could you help me, with this issue?